# several if else if conditions

Tags: java

I have a java class inside there is a method which need to return some integer value based upon conditions met now, I have put some `if...else` conditions inside the method of class as shown below and in comment I have written when this conditions will be executed.

Please advise that my logic inside the method `def()` `if` conditions is correct or not and also please let me know if any conditions executed will it check for remaining conditions or not.

```
class abc
{
  private static SUCCESS = 1;
  private static FAILURE = 2;

  public void int def()
  {
    if (a=20 && b==30)
    {
        if (c==30 && d==40)  // nesting IF condition will go if a=20 & b=30
        { // do something
          return SUCCESS; // IF this condion is met will it check remaing conditions or not
        }
        else
        {
          return FAILURE; // IF this condion is met will it check remaing conditions or not
        }
    }
    else if( g==50 && d==60)
    {
      // do something
      if (t==56 && p==98) // nesting IF condition will go if g=50 & d=60
      {
        // do something
        return SUCCESS; // IF this condion is met will it check remaing conditions or not
      }
      return FAILURE; // IF this condion is met will it check remaing conditions or not
    }
    else
      return FAILURE; // default return means if any othe if or else if block is satisfied then this default value will be returned from the method
  }
}
```

Comment: So… have you actually tested if there’s anything wrong with your code? Or do you want us to check it regardless (we won’t)?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Please let me know that the way I have put the conditions adn the way I am expecting the return statement to be get executed if any conditions is met then will it further check for conditions or it will come out of al

Comment: Once again, why can you not verify this yourself by running your program with different input values and verifying the output is as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

That should be the same

```
if ((a==20 && b==30 && c==30 && d==40) || (g==50 && d==60 && t==56 && p==98))
    return  SUCCESS; 
else
    return  FAILURE;
```

Comment: thanks a lot but there is limitation that I have to go this way only.

Answer (score 0):

In the first if you're missing an equal

```
if (a==0 && b==30)
```

In both if's you can remove the else word (and brackets) just to avoid some no neccesary lines.

Comment: thanks a lot I got it..!!please also advise that say if code goes in if (c==30 && d==40) and it return SUCCESS then further conditions will not be checked, please advise it is correct

Answer (score 0):

Whether your logic is correct is not known, since you haven't provided specifications on how it should work.

However, it's likely that you have at least one problem with:

```
if (a=20 && b==30)
```

since that `=` should almost certainly be a `==`.

In addition, you'll find your code a lot easier to follow if you get out of the mindset that produces things like:

```
if (something)
    return something;
else
    do_something_else;
```

The readability increases greatly if you change that into something like:

```
if (something)
    return something;
do_something_else;
```

*especially* when you have multiple layers like you do.

With respect to your comments:

> IF this condion is met will it check remaing conditions or not.

The answer is no. The instant you `return` from the function, no further code in that function is executed.

Comment: Thanks also please advise that say if code goes in if (c==30 && d==40) and it return SUCCESS then further conditions will not be checked, please advise it is correct

Comment: @user1944559, that's covered by my final bit starting "With respect to ...". No further code is run in the function after a return happens.